# Synonym dictionary implementation?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, dictionary

How should I approach this problem? I basically need to implement a dictionary of synonyms. It takes as input some "word/synonim" pairs and I have to be able to "query" it for the list of all synonims of a word.

For example:

```
Dictionary myDic;

myDic.Add("car", "automobile");
myDic.Add("car", "autovehicle");
myDic.Add("car", "vehicle");
myDic.Add("bike", "vehicle");

myDic.ListOSyns("car") // should return {"automobile","autovehicle","vehicle" ± "car"}
                       // but "bike" should NOT be among the words returned
```

I'll code this in C++, but I'm interested in an overall idea of the implementation, so the question is not exactly language-specific.

PS: The main idea is to have some groups of words (synonyms). In the example above there would be two such groups:

{"automobile","autovehicle","vehicle", "car"}
{"bike", "vehicle"}

"vehicle" belongs to both, "bike" just to the second one, the others just to the first

Comment: are you asking how to implement the dictionary? or the 'related' search (in your example the return of "vehicle"?
also - how deep would you want it? if you also add ("vehicle","motorbike") would "motorbike" be returned as well?

Comment: @skaffman: thanks for the edit, these tags are way more relevant

Comment: darn it, I wrote in wrong; let me edit the post; I would like some insight in both of the problems and depth should be 1.. I'll make the post clearer

Comment: What is the desired return if someone looks up "vehicle"?

Comment: @Steve: good point; for the sake of simplicity let's make it an empty container. That means that each word should be connected to a separate group of words, so my function, Add(string, string) would actually be Add(word, synonym), which means that Add("foo", "foo2") != Add("foo2", "foo")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement it as a `Graph` + `hash table` / `search tree`

each keyword would be a Vertex, and each connection between 2 keywords would be an edge.

a hash table or a search tree will connect from each word to its node (and vice versa).

when a query is submitted - you find the node with your hash/tree and do BFS/DFS of the required depth. (meaning you cannot continue after a certain depth)

complexity: O(E(d)+V(d)) for searching graph (d = depth) (E(d) = number of edges in the relevant depth, same for V(d))

O(1) for creating an edge (not including searching for the node, detailed below its search)

O(logn) / O(1) for finding node (for tree/hash table)

O(logn) /O(1) for adding a keyword to the tree/hash table and O(1) to add a Vertex

p.s. as mentioned: the designer should keep in mind if he needs a directed or indirected Graph, as mentioned in the comments to the question.

 hope that helps...

Comment: It does. And it looks like the hash table would be a better way, since it has a better lookup time (even if, as far as my understanding goes, the complexity for finding/adding keywords to a hashtable is a little bit higher because of the collision problems).

Comment: the hash table`s problem will be if the dictionary is not a fixed size, you will suffer some time loss for rehashing, the average time will still be better, but the maximum latency will be longer, so it's a trade-off you must choose as a designer.

Comment: you're right, but this is merely a college assignment taken a little bit further, so rehashing large dictionaries will not be a problem in this specific case

Comment: With regards to what Steve Jessop pointed out, the graph should be an oriented one, so that "a is a synonym of b" does not imply "b is a synonym of a", although it is possible to have both.

Comment: @cantrem: it's a matter of definition of course. I'll edit my post and mention it - so if someone will see this in the future - he'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

With the clarification in the comments to the question, it's relatively simple since you're not storing groups of mutual synonyms, but rather separately defining the acceptable synonyms for each word. The obvious container is either:

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string> >
```

or:

```
std::multi_map<std::string, std::string>
```

if you're not worried about duplicates being inserted, like this:

```
myDic.Add("car", "automobile");
myDic.Add("car", "auto");
myDic.Add("car", "automobile");
```

In the case of `multi_map`, use the `equal_range` member function to extract the synonyms for each word, maybe like this:

```
struct Dictionary {
    vector<string> ListOSyns(const string &key) const {
        typedef multi_map<string, string>::const_iterator constit;
        pair<constit, constit> x = innermap.equal_range(key);
        vector<string> retval(x.first, x.second);
        retval.push_back(key);
        return retval;
    }
};
```

Finally, if you prefer a hashtable-like structure to a tree-like structure, then `unordered_multimap` might be available in your C++ implementation, and basically the same code works.