# I need to build a HashMap like, Map<Set, Set>. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-structures

My usecase here is, I need to search for a string within a set of strings(say synonyms). If I find the relevant search-word within the set of strings, then I will display the set of values associated with that set of strings. I am currently thinking of implementing it as a Map, but not sure, if that's even possible.

I am confused about the best data-structure that can be used in this scenario?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**
*Replaced Array with Set as it made more sense*

**Scenario:**

Set-1 = {jug,jar,bottle,cup} 
Set-2 = {"Store water", "Store Juice", "Store Coffee"}

For any input I receive from either jug,jar,bottle,cup, I should return the properties associated with it from Set-2. In simple words, I need to return whole of Set-2 when any word from Set-1 matches. Hopefully, this will make my question clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synonym dictionary implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338761/synonym-dictionary-implementation)

Comment: You can simply use a Map with the same value being linked to multiple keys.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Thanks! This is exactly what I was thinking, but was wondering if that would add complexity when the number of elements within Set-1 increase enormously.

Comment: It doesn't add complexity -- it keeps it simple.  And I can't think of a different structure that would be more efficient in either time or space.  The only real problem would be management -- if you wanted to delete a "set-2" entirely you'd have to somehow figure all the keys it was linked to.

Answer (score 0):

you can subclass NSObject for that kind of behaviour.

```
@interface Synonyms : NSObject
@property NSArray *strings;
@property NSArray *values;
-(NSArray *)searchForWord:(NSString *)searchWord;
@end


@implementation Synonyms    
-(NSArray *)searchForWord:(NSString *)searchWord{
    BOOL found=NO;
    //add code to search for that search term in strings array

    if(found)
        return self.values;
    else
        return nil;
}
@end
```

so, first create all these `synonyms instances` and store them in `NSArray`.
Assign strings and values array to each instance.

When user enters search-word, call `searchForWord` function for each element of array.
If found ,it returns not nil object.else no synonym.

**PART 2:**
If you are looking for below kind of behaviour, example below

```
Dictionary myDic;

myDic.Add("car", "automobile");
myDic.Add("car", "autovehicle");
myDic.Add("car", "vehicle");
myDic.Add("bike", "vehicle");

myDic.ListOSyns("car") // should return {"automobile","autovehicle","vehicle" ± "car"}
                       // but "bike" should NOT be among the words returned
```

Then you can use NSDictionary,

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =@{@"car":@[@"automobile",@"autovehicle",@"vehicle"],@"bike":@[@"vehicle"]};

NSArray *values =[dictionary objectForKey:@"search-term"];
if(values==nil)
   //no result
else
   return values;
```

Comment: So basically, it will be an Array of Arrays, right? (Array of synonyms each having a strings and values array inside it). The only concern I have with respect to this implementation is, scalability. How about flattening out the set of keys? So now, I am mapping multiple key strings to one value. Will this make it more efficient, since I am still using a HashMap?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I forgot to acknowledge your help in my earlier post. Question edited for more clarity.